# qtranslate not apply for custom meta boxes and widgets issue

Tags: json, wordpress, widget, meta-boxes, qtranslate-x

I had created one plugin for meta boxes for some post types and created widget but qtranslate not apply for my meta boxes fields and widget fields.
please suggest me i18n-config.json setting for my plugins and widget.

Comment: Wherever in your php code where you adding your strings you need to wrap them as __('Add Field XYZ', 'text-domain'); now any translation plugin might be able to pick and replace those strings.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the text with [__()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) function, before it gets outputed, like so:

```
$text = __($text);
...
```

This should filter the text containing the qTranslate language tags to the currently selected language.

For echoing the text, use [_e()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) instead.